# Why in Linux compiler we have to give additional arguments while compiling and running C programs?

Tags: c, gcc, command-line-arguments

I have implemented semaphores in Linux last year. But for that I have to use **-lpthread**.

Now while implementing log10() function in C, I surfed the INTERNET and I saw that I have to use **-lm**.

I want to know why these kind of command line arguments are necessary in Linux.And Does this rule is compiler oriented?

(In windows Turboc compiler, I never used these kind of arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instructing the compiler to look for certain libraries and use them to try and produce a final object file.

When you were doing your threading code, you used threading primitives. These threading primitives are implemented in a library called `pthread`, `-lpthread` tells the linker to use the library `pthread`, without providing this switch the compiler will not be able to produce a valid object file as it is missing threading code implementation.

On the file system the libraries can be found in /usr/lib and lib (among others) when you look in these directories you will see files start with the `lib` prefix. for example `libpthreadxxxxxx`. You will have to do your own research to figure out what the xxxx means.

The development cycle using unix style tools is very granular on the surface, when you use heavyweight IDE's (read: visual studiio for C++), the IDE implicetly links against loads of standard libraries, so often you do not need to supply the name of the libraries you will commonly use. However, when you start doing more advanced programming you will probably have to install and configure your IDE to use external code libraries. If you were to use threading primitives in visual studio, you most likely will not have to provide the compiler  with information on where to look for threading primitives, Microsoft considers this a common library and every new project will implicitly link against it.

**A little discussion on GCC**

GCC is a very diverse compiler producing code for various different usage scenarios. As such they try to be neutral and do not make assumptions. For example pthread is a particular threading primitives implementation. However, even through now on Linux at least it is the defacto standard, it is not the only one. Other Unix implementation have had different implementation. When such choices exist it is not fair for the compiler developers to implicitly link against libraries. They do however implicitly link against standard libraries; for example G++ is just a wrapper command to the internal compiler code, it is a C++ front-end so it implicitly links against an implementation of the C++ standard library. Similarly the C front end links against a the standard C library.

People often do not want to use certain standard library implementation, and instead they might want to use another implementation, in such cases you have to explicetly inform the compiler to use an implementation that you provide. Such use cases are very granular and are surface level issues with G++. In visual studio, you would have to tinker a lot to make such changes generally, since it is not an anticipated use-case anymore.

wikipedia will provide you with more [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29).

**Edit:** I'll fix the spelling and Grammatical issues later :D

Comment: No problem your answer is great!  I have to know whether the VC++ is less efficient (slower) since it includes all the libraries. Am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily, linking to shared libraries (dynamic linking) is almost as efficient as directly linking against object code (*.o files) or static libraries (.a files). However, linking against the latter 2 cause the code to be directly inserted into your binary. Generally, dynamic libraries are available to every program on your computer, and are shared by lots of programs. Dynamic linking has some runtime over head, but once the program has been started the overhead is negligible. Linking against a huge library statically will on the other hand have more tangible side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The option -l indicates to gcc what libraries must be used for linking. -lpthread stands for "use the pthread library", and -lm stands for "use the m library" which is the math library. These commands are relative to gcc, not linux.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default, **gcc** only **links** the C library (`libc`), which contains the well-known functions `printf`, `scanf`, and many more.

`log10` exists in a different library called `libm`, and thus you need to explictly tell **gcc** to link that library, with `-lm`. The same logic applies for `-lpthread`.

Comment: @JG 1.Are you calling math.h as m library (libm)?  2.what are the predefined methods are there in C library. Since I am not linking explicitly for stdio.h(for using printf and scanf).

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: Yes, the functions declared in `math.h` have implementations in `libm`. You do not explictly link for `libc`, i.e., using `-lc`, because gcc already does that for you by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a backwards, harmful practice. Separating parts of the standard library into separate `.so` files does nothing but increase load time and memory usage. Good luck getting anyone to change it though... Just accept that you have to do it (and that POSIX specifically allows, but does not require, that an implementation require `-lm` for using the math functions and `-lpthread` for using threads, etc.) and move on to more important things.

Or, go pester Drepper about it on the glibc bug tracker/mailing list. He won't change his mind, but if you enjoy flamewars you can get some kicks...